# How to call an Italian mobile from a UK mobile while in Italy?

Tags: italy, cellphones, phone-networks

If I take my UK mobile (cell) phone to Italy how do I call an Italian phone number? I have an iPhone 5s but generic advice appreciated.

I know from the UK I would prefix the number with 00 39 but what about when I'm in Italy? Do I still need to add this?

Comment: From personal experience, yes you do.  That's why I always include international calling code for all my contacts in my address book, regardless of the country they're in.

Comment: I took the habit of entering all phone numbers, regardless of their country, following the international standard +XX (country code), in my mobile phones. So far it has proved a reliable way to dial any [regular] number from any place.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, if you are roaming from the UK, then you should usually dial a foreign country exactly as you would at home.

Bear in mind that prefixing with `+39` is more likely to work on mobile than `00 39`.

Note that to add a + on iOS 10 for iPhone you have hold the 0 key for one second.

Comment: The +39 worked but it is no charged as an international call, there was an article recently saying how ironic it is that's it's cheaper to call Spain from France on a uk mobile than from the uk on a uk mobile. I did also try 0039 but that didn't work.

Comment: See point 4 of this article https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/news/travel/2017/06/free-mobile-roaming-in-the-eu-starts-on-thursday-10-things-you-need-to-know

Comment: As discussed above, this answer is correct for the question being asked.  This may be a quirk of roaming with UK operators however.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, I do not agree with you, I see this answer as the correct one and yours as the wrong one (for my phone, my experience.) Better delete your comment and let the voters (or OP) decide.

Comment: @Willeke that comment was left before the answer was edited to remove a significant section.

Comment: @Notts90 Indeed, I removed the incorrect addition.  But my answer to the question that you asked (rather than the one you didn't about billing) is correct - that it is broadly the same as at home, while his answer that you can dial without the +39 prefix is wrong.

Comment: @MarkPerryman from the comments on that answer I think it actually varies depending on phone operator (BT apparently you don't need +39, vodaphone and o2 you do)

Comment: @Willeke The initial answer *was* completely wrong. The remaining parts of the current answer have been rewritten and do not reflect what I initially pointed out being wrong and a further incorrect section has been deleted by the author. As it is written now, it is at least valid for UK BT mobile and Vodafone customers.

Comment: @MarkPerryman The remaining part of the answer, as it currently stands, is now mostly correct after you edited it twice, completely replacing the initial meaning. No need to pretend that you answered the question correctly before I pointed out all your mistakes.

Comment: Just saying: If you enter +39 an iPhone will not call +39, but whatever is the best depending on where you are. 0 from Italy, 0039 from UK, 01039 from the USA.

Comment: It is best to store numbers in your phonebook with +countrycode - that way dialing will work from anywhere in the world.  That way, there is no need to know the local overseas calling prefix.  (It's often necessary to drop the leading 0 off numbers, e.g. UK numbers, as it is not used when using the international dialing format.) Dialing this way works domestically as well as internationally.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your phone company, your phone will either work as if it was in Italy, or if it was in the UK. If you enter +39.... in your contact list, an iPhone will automatically dial the right number. You can enter +39... on the keypad, which will have the same effect, the phone will do the right thing. I think 0039... will also work; I tried 0044 with my own phone number and it worked (that was O2, other companies might be different). If you just dial the Italian number, your phone might end up calling the UK, as I said, depending on your phone company.

Summary: Dial +39 if you are using an iPhone.

Comment: This is plain wrong information.